# AJAX comment system Validation problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

So i am haveing this page where it is displaying articles andunderneet each article it will have a textarea asking allowing the user to insert a comment.I did the AJAX and it works fine.Some of the validation works fine aswell(Meaning that if the textarea is left empty it will not submit the comment and display an error).The way i am doing this validation is with the ID.So i have multi forms with the same ID.For the commets to be submited it works fine but the validtion doesnt work when i go on a second form for exmaple it only works for the first form

**AJAX code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click','.submitComment',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //send ajax request
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var comment  = $('#comment');
        if (comment.val().length > 1) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_comment.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(form).serialize(), //form serialize data
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //Changeing submit button value text and disableing it
                    $(this).val('Submiting ....').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var item = $(data.html).hide().fadeIn(800);
                    $('.comment-block_' + data.id).append(item);

                    // reset form and button
                    $(form).trigger('reset');
                    $(this).val('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once("menu.php");
?>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script  src="comments.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<?php

    $connection = connectToMySQL();


    $selectPostQuery = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectPostQuery)
        or die("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $postid = $row['ID'];

?>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="titlecontainer">
        <h1><?php echo $row['Title']?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
        <?php echo $row['Content']?>
        </div>
<?php
        if (!empty($row['ImagePath'])) #This will check if there is an path in the textfield
        {
?>
            <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="images/<?php echo "$row[ImagePath]"; ?>" alt="Article Image">
            </div>
<?php
        }
?>
        <div class="timestampcontainer">
        <b>Date posted :</b><?php echo $row['TimeStamp']?>
        <b>Author :</b> Admin
        </div>
<?php
        #Selecting comments corresponding to the post
        $selectCommentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tblcomments` LEFT JOIN `tblusers` ON tblcomments.userID = tblusers.ID WHERE tblcomments.PostID ='$postid'";

        $commentResult = mysqli_query($connection,$selectCommentQuery)
            or die ("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

        #renderinf the comments

        echo '<div class="comment-block_' . $postid .'">';

        while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentResult)) 
        {
?>
            <div class="commentcontainer">
            <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :<?php echo $commentRow['Username']?></h1></div>
            <div class="commentcontent"><?php echo $commentRow['Content']?></div>
            <div class="commenttimestamp"><?php echo $commentRow['Timestamp']?></div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
?>
        </div>
<?php 

        if (!empty($_SESSION['userID']) ) 
        {
?>
            <form method="POST" class="post-frm" action="index.php" >
            <label>New Comment</label>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="comment"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $postid ?>">
            <input type="submit" name ="submit" class="submitComment"/>
            </form>
<?php
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<br /> <br /><br />"; 
    }
 require_once("footer.php") ?>
```

Again the problem being is the first form works fine but the second one and onwaord dont work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var comment  = $('.comment',form);
```

instead of

```
var comment  = $('#comment');
```

That way you're targeting the textarea belonging to the form you're validating

ps.

remove the id's from the elements or make them unique with php, all element id's should be unique